# Wordpress - No value for custom post type column

Tags: wordpress, docker

I cannot display column values for a custom post type. I use correct filters and actions according to WordPress documentation.

To make sure I'm doing everything right I've prepared a simple plugin based on examples from official documentation to initiate a **custom post type and add a custom column**.
Unfortunately, the column I added is still not filled with "lorem ipsum".

Analyzing Wordpress code, I noticed that the `column_default` method defined in
`wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php` where the action `manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column` is defined is not executed.

[image]

Here's the full plugin code.

- Post type: `xpost`
- Custom column: `xpostcol`

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: XPlugin
 */

add_action('init', 'xplugin_register_post_type');
add_filter('manage_xpost_posts_columns', 'xplugin_manage_posts_columns');
add_action('manage_xpost_posts_custom_column', 'xplugin_manage_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'xplugin_register_activation_hook');

function xplugin_register_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'=> 'XPosts'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'xpost' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),        
    );

    register_post_type( 'xpost', $args );
}

function xplugin_register_activation_hook() {
    xplugin_register_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function xplugin_manage_posts_columns($columns) {
    unset($columns['author']);
    $new_columns = array('xpostcol' => 'XPost Column');
    return array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
}

function xplugin_manage_posts_custom_column($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
        case 'xpostcol' :
                echo 'Lorem ipsum';
            break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your plugin code is working perfectly for me so the problem isn't there.

Comment: I can't believe it doesn't work for me either. The plugin is minimalistic and based on   WordPress documentation solutions. The method `column_default` that is responsible for calling the action hook `manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column` seems to be unused, because when I try to interrupt it with `die()` or display an echo or dump, nothing happens.

Comment: As I said, your plugin is working so the problem isn't in the code you've shown us. Something else if interfering with it. Without seeing the rest of your setup, we can't really help but you can troubleshoot the problem to try narrow it down e.g. Try disabling your plugins one by one to see if any of those are causing the problem. If that doesn't work, change your theme to one of the default themes (e.g. twentytwenty) to see if the problem is in your theme code.

Comment: I've tested this plugin on external server and it really works correctly. I was currently using a WordPress running on the docker containers. I've tested few different images `wordpress:latest`, `wordpress:php7.2` etc. but none of them works the same way as WordPress installed on external server. I have no idea what's wrong with my local configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin works incorrectly when I run WordPress container from the official Docker image. In case of running custom container based on Apache + PHP + MySQL and manual WordPress installation, the plugin works fine.